# Can you get the good endings if you play a purely renegade Shepard?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is it possible to get the best endings playing as a renegade? Or the choices you make (if you are not tempted to break character) are inherently evil at some point, which would prevent them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. Here is a list of [largely spoiler free ending info](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Endings) with requirements listed, you have to click to expand the spoiler for each ending.

**Morality doesn't affect whether you can get the "best" ending**, though whether or not you saved the Collector base in ME2 forces your hand for *certain* ending levels.