# Second play through. Femshep Paragon. Which missions would get in the way of my paragon(ness)?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There was that one mission on Tuchanka(?) with the rachnis and I tried both options and noticed I got plus 5 renegade for both endings to that mission, Leave the queen or free her.

Don't link me to videos or anything, reading ftw!

Just post the name o' the missions and telling me what to say.

Comment: Just FYI, it shouldn't matter so much: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54335/can-you-get-the-good-endings-if-you-play-a-purely-renegade-shepard

Answer (score 1):

Renegade and Paragon-ness is not important in Mass Effect 3. It changes what order some interrupts will appear, but nothing else.

The only thing that matters is your overall reputation (your paragon + renegade).

Bioware finally lets me play morally gray (grey?) characters!

Comment: Yeah, but I reeeeeeaaaaaaaaallllllllyyyyyyy want perfect paragon-ness.

Comment: Some actions have no paragon resolution. The best answer here is to have killed the rachni originally, 'cause then you won't have to abandon the krogan (renegade) or abandon the queen (renegade).

Comment: Oh, I'm playing Mass effect 3 with no imports. Thanks.

Comment: Np! 11 more to go

Comment: This is why I like one of the quotes about the game: There will be blood on your hands.  There is, of course, a third option: don't do this optional mission.  Killing the rachni queen is the renegade option in ME1, which can taint imported saves (although it wouldn't be much).  However, you'd be giving up to 175 worth of War Assets.

Comment: Thanks! I remember not to do that mission and thanks for the number of war assets.

Comment: @DylanIp don't forget to give me an upvote if I helped! Karma and all!

Comment: Yes it is - the final conversation reputation option apparently requires a *perfect* paragon/renegade score.

Answer (score 1):

That mission results in only paragon options for that choice if the Rachni queen died. I think it is a special case and only that one mission has no paragon option.

Always pick the top right option for paragon, I don't believe any other morality choices are forced.

Comment: Thanks. Best answer yet. But this mission I'm talking about appears to be renegade.

Comment: That's incorrect. If you have 0 renegade, reputation translates into 100% paragon, 0% renegade.

Answer (score 1):

You are forced to receive 5 renegade points if you complete Attican Traverse: Krogan Team.

There is no other possible outcome if you chose to play this mission. The Mass Effect Wikia has a morality guide for every game, covering almost all P/R decisions.

I've highlighted the excerpt pertinent to your question:

> If Grunt is leader of Aralakh Company
>
> - 2 Paragon for saying "Good to have you here."
> - 2 Renegade for saying "Keep them in line."
>
> If Urdnot Dagg is leader of Arakalh Company
>
> - 2 Paragon for saying "Good."
> - 2 Renegade for saying "Keep your krogan in line."
>
> Rachni queen, if rachni queen was spared in Mass Effect
>
> - 2 Paragon for saying "It's over now."
> - 2 Renegade for saying "You're a puppet." Breeder surrogate, if rachni queen was killed in Mass Effect
> - 2 Paragon for saying "The Reapers are gone."
> - 2 Renegade for saying "You're a danger."
>
> If Wrex is clan chief
>
> - 2 Paragon for saying "You did."
> - 2 Renegade for saying "It wasn't pretty."
>
> If Wreav is clan chief and rachni saved
>
> - 2 Paragon for saying "Excuse me?"
> - 2 Renegade for saying "You're a coward."
>
> Mission completion
>
> - 5 Reputation
> - **5 Renegade**

[ME3 Morality Guide](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Morality_Guide_%28Mass_Effect_3%29)